# Rename keys in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hey all:
I have this array:

```
$names = array('a','b','c'); 
foreach($names as $key => $value ) {
    echo $key;
}
```

where `a, b, c` come from a name[] field

The input is:

```
0
1
2
```

There is an array function to replace the output result as:

```
1
2
3
```

I want to rename the first key because I'll insert theme into a mysql table.

Answer (score 3):

Why rename? Just use `$key + 1` when needed.

Comment: I'll use the $key in as [$key] so I can't added a value to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = count($names) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) 
    $names[$i + 1] = $names[$i];
unset($names[0]);
```

or

```
array_unshift($names, 0); 
unset($names[0]);
```

or

Just use $key+1 in your query rather than changing the array.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution:

```
$names = array(1 => 'a','b','c'); 
foreach($names as $key => $value ) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not match the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this if you want to increase all by 1:

```
$names = array('a','b','c'); 
foreach($names as $key => $value ) {
    $key = $key+1;
}
```

or

```
$names = array('a','b','c'); 
foreach($names as $key => $value ) {
    if($key==1) {
        $key = $key+1;
    }
}
```

but the second one would not make any sense since it would just be replaced by the second array element.